# How do I check if two Maps are equal in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

How do you check if two maps are equal in OCaml no matter the order ?

For example :

Map 1 :

```
var1 ->  [Neg]

var2 ->  [Pos; Zero; Neg]

var3 ->  [Neg; Pos]
```

Map2 :

```
var1 ->  [Neg]

var2 ->  [Pos; Zero; Neg]

var3 ->  [Pos; Neg]
```

What I've tried :

```
Map.equal (fun x y -> x = y)
```

This returns false, as it considers the order is important.

Should I sort the lists, or is there a more efficient functional way ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you include some actual code that creates these maps that should compare equal so that it's 100% clear what data structures and types you're working with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document for `Map.equal` says:

> `equal cmp m1 m2` tests whether the maps `m1` and `m2` are equal,
> that is, contain equal keys and associate them with equal data.
> `cmp` is the equality predicate used to compare the data associated
> with the keys.

You are specifically asking to use `=` as your equality predicate, but you're also saying that it's not what you want.

The solution is to supply the equality predicate that you do want.

If you want to know whether two lists contain the same elements regardless of order, you can sort the lists and compare the sorted values.

```
let equal_contents a b =
    List.sort compare a = List.sort compare b
```

You can also keep the values in the map in a canonical order (i.e., sorted). Then the code you give above will work.

Comment: I thaught there was an other built-in way. Thanks again (two times today)

Comment: Not to be glib, but the generalized equality predicate *is* the built-in way. If a language has a lot of built-in special cases, it's a possible sign that it lacks sufficiently powerful abstraction facilities.